# file_get_contents (PHP) - альтернатива на javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

Пробовал `window.location.replace` и `window.location.assign`, но все время делается редирект на сайт, откуда парсится информация. Как сделать так, чтобы информация выводилась на домене, где расположен скрипт, а не где расположен оригинал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

То есть, ты хочешь получить содержимое файла с удаленного сайта через js? Если домен расположения js и домен, откуда ты хочешь получить содержимое, будут одинаковыми, то гугли в сторону ajax. Если домены разные, то, в общем случае, никак.

Comment: Обрати внимание, код mctrane не работает между разными доменами. Только в пределах одного домена.

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю, поможет или нет, но тут сайт качает страницу на сервак и парсит по разным словам в теле страницы: [Определение CMS](http://2ip.ru/cms/).

Answer (score 0):

Браузеры по умолчанию запрещают кроссдоменные запросы с помощью javascript - то есть, вы не сможете получить с помощью javascript контент содержащийся на другом домене.

Но, вы можете реализовать это так:
ваш сайт делает ajax запрос (например с помощью jquery $.post()) на ваш сервер -> потом, ваш сервер с помощтбью file_get_contents запрашивает сторонний сайт и возвращает результат в ответ на ваш ajax запрос -> далее вы можете вывести его на странице

Answer (score -1):

Ниже аналог функции php.

Хотя сам оптимизировал сайт, делая обновление только контента на js, я не пользуюсь этой функцией. Сделал сам на ajax. Ничего сложного, если php знаешь, то почитай книжку ajax+php и тогда сам сможешь сделать, я сам эту книгу до конца не читал, так часиков 5 почитал и мне хватило для этой цели.

```
function file_get_contents (url, flags, context, offset, maxLen) {
        // Read the entire file into a string
        //
        // version: 906.111
        // +      input by: Jani Hartikainen
        // +   improved by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
        // +   improved by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
        // +   input by: Raphael (Ao) RUDLER    // +   bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
        // %        note 1: This function uses XmlHttpRequest and cannot retrieve resource from different domain without modifications.
        // %        note 2: Synchronous by default (as in PHP) so may lock up browser. Can
        // %        note 2: get async by setting a custom "phpjs.async" property to true and "notification" for an
        // %        note 2: optional callback (both as context params, with responseText, and other JS-specific    // %        note 2: request properties available via 'this'). Note that file_get_contents() will not return the text
        // %        note 2: in such a case (use this.responseText within the callback). Or, consider using
        // %        note 2: jQuery's: $('#divId').load('http://url') instead.
        // %        note 3: The context argument is only implemented for http, and only partially (see below for
        // %        note 3: "Presently unimplemented HTTP context options"); also the arguments passed to    // %        note 3: notification are incomplete
        // *     example 1: file_get_contents('http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net/pj_test_supportfile_1.htm');
        // *     returns 1: '123'
        // Note: could also be made to optionally add to global $http_response_header as per http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php
        var tmp, headers = [],        newTmp = [],
            k = 0,
            i = 0,
            href = '',
            pathPos = -1,        flagNames = 0,
            content = null,
            http_stream = false;
        var func = function (value) {
            return value.substring(1) !== '';    };

        // BEGIN REDUNDANT
        this.php_js = this.php_js || {};
        this.php_js.ini = this.php_js.ini || {};    // END REDUNDANT
        var ini = this.php_js.ini;
        context = context || this.php_js.default_streams_context || null;

        if (!flags) {        flags = 0;
        }
        var OPTS = {
            FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH: 1,
            FILE_TEXT: 32,        FILE_BINARY: 64
        };
        if (typeof flags === 'number') { // Allow for a single string or an array of string flags
            flagNames = flags;
        } else {        flags = [].concat(flags);
            for (i = 0; i < flags.length; i++) {
                if (OPTS[flags[i]]) {
                    flagNames = flagNames | OPTS[flags[i]];
                }        }
        }

        if (flagNames & OPTS.FILE_BINARY && (flagNames & OPTS.FILE_TEXT)) { // These flags shouldn't be together
            throw 'You cannot pass both FILE_BINARY and FILE_TEXT to file_get_contents()';    }

        if ((flagNames & OPTS.FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH) && ini.include_path && ini.include_path.local_value) {
            var slash = ini.include_path.local_value.indexOf('/') !== -1 ? '/' : '\\';
            url = ini.include_path.local_value + slash + url;    } else if (!/^(https?|file):/.test(url)) { // Allow references within or below the same directory (should fix to allow other relative references or root reference; could make dependent on parse_url())
            href = this.window.location.href;
            pathPos = url.indexOf('/') === 0 ? href.indexOf('/', 8) - 1 : href.lastIndexOf('/');
            url = href.slice(0, pathPos + 1) + url;
        } 
        if (context) {
            var http_options = context.stream_options && context.stream_options.http;
            http_stream = !! http_options;
        } 
        if (!context || http_stream) {
            var req = this.window.ActiveXObject ? new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') : new XMLHttpRequest();
            if (!req) {
                throw new Error('XMLHttpRequest not supported');        }

            var method = http_stream ? http_options.method : 'GET';
            var async = !! (context && context.stream_params && context.stream_params['phpjs.async']);
             if (ini['phpjs.ajaxBypassCache'] && ini['phpjs.ajaxBypassCache'].local_value) {
                url += (url.match(/\?/) == null ? "?" : "&") + (new Date()).getTime(); // Give optional means of forcing bypass of cache
            }

            req.open(method, url, async);        if (async) {
                var notification = context.stream_params.notification;
                if (typeof notification === 'function') {
                    // Fix: make work with req.addEventListener if available: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest
                    if (0 && req.addEventListener) { // Unimplemented so don't allow to get here/*
                        req.addEventListener('progress', updateProgress, false);
                        req.addEventListener('load', transferComplete, false);
                        req.addEventListener('error', transferFailed, false);
                        req.addEventListener('abort', transferCanceled, false);                    */
                    } else {
                        req.onreadystatechange = function (aEvt) { // aEvt has stopPropagation(), preventDefault(); see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NsIDOMEvent
                            // Other XMLHttpRequest properties: multipart, responseXML, status, statusText, upload, withCredentials
    /*    PHP Constants:
        STREAM_NOTIFY_RESOLVE   1       A remote address required for this stream has been resolved, or the resolution failed. See severity  for an indication of which happened.
        STREAM_NOTIFY_CONNECT   2     A connection with an external resource has been established.
        STREAM_NOTIFY_AUTH_REQUIRED 3     Additional authorization is required to access the specified resource. Typical issued with severity level of STREAM_NOTIFY_SEVERITY_ERR.
        STREAM_NOTIFY_MIME_TYPE_IS  4     The mime-type of resource has been identified, refer to message for a description of the discovered type.    STREAM_NOTIFY_FILE_SIZE_IS  5     The size of the resource has been discovered.
        STREAM_NOTIFY_REDIRECTED    6     The external resource has redirected the stream to an alternate location. Refer to message .
        STREAM_NOTIFY_PROGRESS  7     Indicates current progress of the stream transfer in bytes_transferred and possibly bytes_max as well.
        STREAM_NOTIFY_COMPLETED 8     There is no more data available on the stream.
        STREAM_NOTIFY_FAILURE   9     A generic error occurred on the stream, consult message and message_code for details.    STREAM_NOTIFY_AUTH_RESULT   10     Authorization has been completed (with or without success).

        STREAM_NOTIFY_SEVERITY_INFO 0     Normal, non-error related, notification.
        STREAM_NOTIFY_SEVERITY_WARN 1     Non critical error condition. Processing may continue.
        STREAM_NOTIFY_SEVERITY_ERR  2     A critical error occurred. Processing cannot continue.    */
                            var objContext = {
                                responseText: req.responseText,
                                responseXML: req.responseXML,
                                status: req.status,                            statusText: req.statusText,
                                readyState: req.readyState,
                                evt: aEvt
                            }; // properties are not available in PHP, but offered on notification via 'this' for convenience
                            // notification args: notification_code, severity, message, message_code, bytes_transferred, bytes_max (all int's except string 'message')                        // Need to add message, etc.
                            var bytes_transferred;
                            switch (req.readyState) {
                            case 0:
                                //     UNINITIALIZED     open() has not been called yet.                            notification.call(objContext, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0);
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                //     LOADING     send() has not been called yet.
                                notification.call(objContext, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0);                            break;
                            case 2:
                                //     LOADED     send() has been called, and headers and status are available.
                                notification.call(objContext, 0, 0, '', 0, 0, 0);
                                break;                        case 3:
                                //     INTERACTIVE     Downloading; responseText holds partial data.
                                bytes_transferred = req.responseText.length * 2; // One character is two bytes
                                notification.call(objContext, 7, 0, '', 0, bytes_transferred, 0);
                                break;                        case 4:
                                //     COMPLETED     The operation is complete.
                                if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
                                    bytes_transferred = req.responseText.length * 2; // One character is two bytes
                                    notification.call(objContext, 8, 0, '', req.status, bytes_transferred, 0);                            } else if (req.status === 403) { // Fix: These two are finished except for message
                                    notification.call(objContext, 10, 2, '', req.status, 0, 0);
                                } else { // Errors
                                    notification.call(objContext, 9, 2, '', req.status, 0, 0);
                                }                            break;
                            default:
                                throw 'Unrecognized ready state for file_get_contents()';
                            }
                        }                }
                }
            }

            if (http_stream) {            var sendHeaders = http_options.header && http_options.header.split(/\r?\n/);
                var userAgentSent = false;
                for (i = 0; i < sendHeaders.length; i++) {
                    var sendHeader = sendHeaders[i];
                    var breakPos = sendHeader.search(/:\s*/);                var sendHeaderName = sendHeader.substring(0, breakPos);
                    req.setRequestHeader(sendHeaderName, sendHeader.substring(breakPos + 1));
                    if (sendHeaderName === 'User-Agent') {
                        userAgentSent = true;
                    }            }
                if (!userAgentSent) {
                    var user_agent = http_options.user_agent || (ini.user_agent && ini.user_agent.local_value);
                    if (user_agent) {
                        req.setRequestHeader('User-Agent', user_agent);                }
                }
                content = http_options.content || null;
    /*
                // Presently unimplemented HTTP context options            var request_fulluri = http_options.request_fulluri || false; // When set to TRUE, the entire URI will be used when constructing the request. (i.e. GET http://www.example.com/path/to/file.html HTTP/1.0). While this is a non-standard request format, some proxy servers require it.
                var max_redirects = http_options.max_redirects || 20; // The max number of redirects to follow. Value 1 or less means that no redirects are followed.
                var protocol_version = http_options.protocol_version || 1.0; // HTTP protocol version
                var timeout = http_options.timeout || (ini.default_socket_timeout && ini.default_socket_timeout.local_value); // Read timeout in seconds, specified by a float
                var ignore_errors = http_options.ignore_errors || false; // Fetch the content even on failure status codes.            */
            }

            if (flagNames & OPTS.FILE_TEXT) { // Overrides how encoding is treated (regardless of what is returned from the server)
                var content_type = 'text/html';            if (http_options && http_options['phpjs.override']) { // Fix: Could allow for non-HTTP as well
                    content_type = http_options['phpjs.override']; // We use this, e.g., in gettext-related functions if character set
                    //   overridden earlier by bind_textdomain_codeset()
                } else {
                    var encoding = (ini['unicode.stream_encoding'] && ini['unicode.stream_encoding'].local_value) || 'UTF-8';                if (http_options && http_options.header && (/^content-type:/im).test(http_options.header)) { // We'll assume a content-type expects its own specified encoding if present
                        content_type = http_options.header.match(/^content-type:\s*(.*)$/im)[1]; // We let any header encoding stand
                    }
                    if (!(/;\s*charset=/).test(content_type)) { // If no encoding
                        content_type += '; charset=' + encoding;                }
                }
                req.overrideMimeType(content_type);
            }
            // Default is FILE_BINARY, but for binary, we apparently deviate from PHP in requiring the flag, since many if not        //     most people will also want a way to have it be auto-converted into native JavaScript text instead
            else if (flagNames & OPTS.FILE_BINARY) { // Trick at https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_XMLHttpRequest to get binary
                req.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=x-user-defined');
                // Getting an individual byte then requires:
                // responseText.charCodeAt(x) & 0xFF; // throw away high-order byte (f7) where x is 0 to responseText.length-1 (see notes in our substr())        }

            if (http_options && http_options['phpjs.sendAsBinary']) { // For content sent in a POST or PUT request (use with file_put_contents()?)
                req.sendAsBinary(content); // In Firefox, only available FF3+
            } else {            req.send(content);
            }

            tmp = req.getAllResponseHeaders();
            if (tmp) {            tmp = tmp.split('\n');
                for (k = 0; k < tmp.length; k++) {
                    if (func(tmp[k])) {
                        newTmp.push(tmp[k]);
                    }            }
                tmp = newTmp;
                for (i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
                    headers[i] = tmp[i];
                }            this.$http_response_header = headers; // see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php
            }

            if (offset || maxLen) {
                if (maxLen) {                return req.responseText.substr(offset || 0, maxLen);
                }
                return req.responseText.substr(offset);
            }
            return req.responseText;    }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Ловите минус! У вас синтаксическая ошибка в коде!

Comment: Код из источника, от Kevin van Zonneveld. Ситаксическая ошибка - это фигня) легко поправимо)